# Binding values from diferent views Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I am pretty new to Xamarin and it's been a pretty frustating experience. After a while trying to learn the basics watching some tutorials I've finnaly managed to get a grisp on binding objects and it seemed that i was finally ready to move on.

Well, I was wrong. I am trying to workout how to bind objects from different views (which I thought should be quite simple), but nothing I do seems to work.

I have this first view with bindinng objects which I wanted to be reflected into the next one. I thought simply binding them to the same variable and using the same view model would be enough to the input entry on the first page to be printed in the second page label. But that is not happening. Can any one help, or refer to good begginer material that I can learn it from?

First View XAML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Conferencia.Views.AddBagPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Conferencia.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:AddBagViewModel">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:AddBagViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*,Auto,Auto,*,Auto,*">
        <Entry
                Text="{Binding RegCodeText}"
                Grid.Row="2"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Placeholder="00000000000000000"/>
        <Label 
                x:Name="RegLabel"
                Text="{Binding RegCodeText}"
                FontSize="Medium"
                Grid.Row="3"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button
            Command="{Binding NewRegister}"
            Grid.Row="5"
            Text="Registrar"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

First View cs

```
using Conferencia.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Conferencia.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AddBagPage : ContentPage
    {
        public AddBagPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext =  new AddBagViewModel();

        }

    }
}
```

Second Page XAML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Conferencia.Views.CreateBagListPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Conferencia.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:AddBagViewModel">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:AddBagViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding RegCodeText}"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Second Page cs

```
using Conferencia.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Conferencia.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CreateBagListPage : ContentPage
    {
        public CreateBagListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new AddBagViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

View Model

```
using MvvmHelpers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Conferencia.ViewModels
{
    public class AddBagViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        public AddBagViewModel()
        {
            NewRegister = new Command(OnNewRegister);
        }
        public ICommand NewRegister { get; }
        async void OnNewRegister()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("CreateBagListPage");
        }

        public string regCode = "";
        public string RegCodeText
        {
            get => regCode;
            set => SetProperty(ref regCode, value);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to share data, you have to use the same **instance** of the VM on both page.  You are creating **new instances** of the VM for each page, so of course they will not share any data

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said instantiating the VM on app.xml did the trick

```
<Application.Resources>
   <viewmodels:AddBagViewModel x:Key="AddBagViewModel" />
<Application.Resources>
```

Calling it on view like this

```
BindingContext="{StaticResource AddBagViewModel}"
```